# php: When to use the scope resolution symbol (::) after an include / require_once?

Tags: php

All,

I'd like to understand

I'm looking at this code sample from [w3Style's front controller tutorial](http://www.w3style.co.uk/a-lightweight-and-flexible-front-controller-for-php-5):

index.php

```
<?php
define("PAGE_DIR", dirname(__FILE__) . "/pages");
require_once "FrontController.php";
FrontController::createInstance()->dispatch();
```

Why is the `::` required in this case?

Does it have to do with the flexibility of one day creating a different class in "FrontController.php" which would also have a method of this name?  Or is it to address the case when one would have several includes of different classes, all incorporating some same method name?

Thanks,

JDelage

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Comment: It is not at all related to `require`/`include`. It is just how classes can work.

Comment: Yes I've read that but I'm still unclear.  Thanks for posting the link, I should have included it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FrontController` seems to be a [Singleton class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php).

The  `createInstance()` method is called statically (hence the `::`) and creates an object instance. Then, the `dispatch()` method is executed on the resulting object (hence the `->`).

Answer (score 1):

It's because `FrontController` is a class with a `createInstance()` static method.

Comment: So had the method not been static, we wouldn't have needed the operator?

Comment: If the method wasn't static then you'd have to instantiate the class and use `->` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When calling a class method which does not require a instance of the class (-> static call), you can call it by ::

Comment: You have to declare the method static, though, to avoid an E_STRICT notice (at least as of PHP 5.3, don't know about earlier versions)

Answer (score 0):

The guy tried to adopt the Singleton Pattern but there is mistake in his code:

This:

```
class FrontController {
  public static function createInstance() {
    if (!defined("PAGE_DIR")) {
      exit("Critical error: Cannot proceed without PAGE_DIR.");
    }
    $instance = new self();
    return $instance;
  }
```

Should become something like:

```
class FrontController {
  var $instance = NULL;
  public static function createInstance() {
    if (!defined("PAGE_DIR")) {
      exit("Critical error: Cannot proceed without PAGE_DIR.");
    }
    if($this->instance == NULL) {
      $this->instance = new self();
    }

    return $this->instance;
  }
```

That is just one approach but there are also different but similar. The idea is you have just one instance of this specific class and there is no duplication.